# android messages not saving through sms manager

Tags: android

Hi i have the following code. it doesnot save the messages to my inbox after sending!! i have added all that are required in manifest.xml file. pls help me

{

```
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(pnumber, null, message, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(context,"Message Sent to " + pnumber,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ContentValues my_values = new ContentValues();
        my_values.put("body", message);
        my_values.put("address", pnumber);          
        context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), my_values);
```

}

Comment: doesn't save then what's happening? Any exception then post logcat. show your Manifest permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest? Are you trying from the emulator or a real device, are the SMS sent (no exception in the logcat)?